# insert data into two tables using foreach based on checkbox in php

Tags: php, mysql

need help

can anyone correct my code for inserting data into two tables using foreach based on the checkbox that I checked

```
<?php


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'a.karat');
if(isset($_POST['simpan']))
{

$poNo           = $_POST['poNo'];   
$prNo           = $_POST['prNo'];   
$cabang         = $_POST['cabang'];
$supplier       = $_POST['supplier'];   
$tanggal_po     = $_POST['tanggal_po'];
$tanggal_kirim  = $_POST['tanggal_kirim'];
$note           = $_POST['note'];
$ppn            = $_POST['ppn'];
$grandtotal     = $_POST['grandtotal'];

$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO po (poNo,prNo,cabang,supplier,tanggal_po,tanggal_kirim,note,ppn,grandtotal)VALUES('$poNo', '$prNo','$cabang', '$supplier', '$tanggal_po',  '$tanggal_kirim', '$note', '$ppn','$grandtotal') mysqli_connect_error()");

$check=$_POST['check'];
foreach($check as $i)
{
    $prcode=$_POST['productCode'.$i];
    $prname=$_POST['productName'.$i];
    $qty=$_POST['qty'.$i];
    $harga=$_POST['harga'.$i];
    $diskon=$_POST['diskon'.$i];
    $total=$_POST['total'.$i];
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"insert into detail_po (poNo,productCode,productName,qty,harga,diskon,total) value ('$poNo', '$prcode', '$prname', '$qty', '$harga','$diskon','$total',)mysqli_connect_error()");
}
if($query)
{
?>
<script>
alert("success");
</script>
<?php
}
}

?>
```

what am I missing, there is no error messages

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mysqli_connect_error()` from your query. This is causing the query to fail. Also your insert statement is incorrect. Replace `value` with `values`.
There is extra comma in your second query.

Proper way to check for any errors in query is

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"insert into detail_po
(poNo,productCode,productName,qty,harga,diskon,total)
values ('$poNo', '$prcode', '$prname', '$qty', '$harga','$diskon','$total')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: i copy and paste your code but still nothing happen

Comment: Did you correct other errors I mentioned in my post?

Comment: yes I did sir,   $query = mysqli_query($con,"insert into detail_po (poNo,productCode,productName,qty,harga,diskon,total) values ('".$poNo."', '".$prcode."', '".$prname."', '".$qty."', '".$harga."','".$diskon."','".$total."')") or die(mysqli_error($con)); but no data was inserted

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get an error with this line

$query = mysqli_query($con,"insert into detail_po (poNo,productCode,productName,qty,harga,diskon,total) value ('$poNo', '$prcode', '$prname', '$qty', '$harga','$diskon','$total',)mysqli_connect_error()");

Notice your comma after the '$total',? Remove that and try to run again.

Comment: i have remove the coma, still nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

First `mysqli_connect_error()` function is used to check MySQL connection is established or not and it should be at top, where you have database connection.
Remove it from `INSERT queries`.

**Once suggestion**

Rather than using second query in `FOREACH` loop you can create `bulk INSERT` query

Answer (score 0):

$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO po (poNo,prNo,cabang,supplier,tanggal_po,tanggal_kirim,note,ppn,grandtotal)VALUES('".$poNo."', '".$prNo."','".$cabang."', '".$supplier."', '".$tanggal_po."',  '".$tanggal_kirim."', '".$note."', '".$ppn."','".$grandtotal."') mysqli_connect_error()");

$query = mysqli_query($con,"insert into detail_po (poNo,productCode,productName,qty,harga,diskon,total) value ('".$poNo."', '".$prcode."', '".$prname."', '".$qty."', '".$harga."','".$diskon."','".$total."',)mysqli_connect_error()");

Comment: i copy and paste your code but still no data is saved

Comment: also remove mysqli_connect_error() and  try echo your sql query and then run it on mysql to check error .